# Unable to send Mails through SMTP using Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

i need to send mails to 60 to 100 students at a time when i click on Send Button. It is working good if i have 6 to 7 students but when i start sending to 60 students my code shows the following error

**Insufficient system storage. The server response was: Too many emails per connection.**

Here is My code

protected void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
     if (drptopics.SelectedValue == "-1")
            {
                Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Please select one Topic');</script>");
            }


     else

     {

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=xxxx; User Id=sa; Password=xxxx; Initial Catalog=xxxx; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    conn.Open();


    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "select EMail_1 from Student_Info where Branch_Code='ap' and Student_ID in(select Student_ID from Admissions where Branch_Code='ap' and Batch_ID='" + txtbatchid.Text + "')";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);




    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0] != null)
    {
        int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;


        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
            mm.To.Add(new MailAddress(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString()));
            mm.From = new MailAddress("xxxxx@abc.com");
            mm.Subject = "SMS and Interview Questions of Oracle 11g DBA";
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;





            //Day 1 Architecture 1
             if (drptopics.SelectedValue == "1")
            {
                Attachment attachment1 = new Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/Oracle 11g DBA/Day 1/Architecture-1-I.doc")); //create the attachment
                mm.Attachments.Add(attachment1);
                Attachment attachment2 = new Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/Oracle 11g DBA/Day 1/Architecture1-S.doc")); //create the attachment
                mm.Attachments.Add(attachment2);

            }


            //Day 2 Architecture 2
            else if (drptopics.SelectedValue == "2")
            {
                Attachment attachment1 = new Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/Oracle 11g DBA/Day 2/Architecture-2-I.doc")); //create the attachment
                mm.Attachments.Add(attachment1);
                Attachment attachment2 = new Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/Oracle 11g DBA/Day 2/Architecture2-S.doc")); //create the attachment
                mm.Attachments.Add(attachment2);
            }

             mm.Body = "<html><head><body><h1>Thank you for choosing Wilshire</h1><br><b>Team Wilshire<b></body></head></html>";
            SmtpClient s = new SmtpClient("smtp.net4india.com");
            s.Send(mm);


        }

    }
```

}

Please tell me the solution........................

Comment: Is the body identical? Put all recipients in the BCC, and send with a single e-mail.

Comment: Depending on the Query  cmd.CommandText = "select EMail_1 from Student_Info where Branch_Code='ap' and Student_ID in(select Student_ID from Admissions where Branch_Code='ap' and Batch_ID='" + txtbatchid.Text + "')";  the Emails will be changing

Comment: In my answer I show how you can put all recipients in BCC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SmtpClient.SendAsync()` could lead to other problems (SMTP servers set a maximum mail number per minute to avoid spam)!

Since the mails are identical, the solution is **1 single mail with all recipients as hidden recipients** (`Bcc`)!

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
  mm.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString()));
}
mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxxxx@abc.com");
mm.From = new MailAddress("xxxxx@abc.com");
mm.Subject = "SMS and Interview Questions of Oracle 11g DBA";

....

SmtpClient s = new SmtpClient("smtp.net4india.com");
s.Send(mm);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says 'Too many emails per connection'. Why not send fewer emails per connection? Add a loop and dispose of the connection every few e-mails and then create a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Use `SmtpClient.SendAsync Method` to send mail it's sending mail background one by one.

[Reference Link 1](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SendSmtpAsync.aspx)

[Reference Link 2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1550758.aspx/1)

Comment: I used SendAsync() method there I got this Error "Asynchronous operations are not allowed in this context. Page starting an asynchronous operation has to have the Async attribute set to true and an asynchronous operation can only be started on a page prior to PreRenderComplete event."

Answer (score 1):

May be You can also use ASP.NET4.5 New feature if you are working on the latest framework.

Refer Link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/599756/Five-Great-NET-Framework-4-5-Features

Feature 1: async and await (code markers)